# Cannot take off error without proper description

Tags: android, android-studio, dji-sdk

**SDK version:** `4.7`

I am facing an issue with certain errors thrown by the SDK. I have attached two screenshots for reference.

[Image from sample app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/072YF.jpg):

Following error message is received:

> Unknown error (code: 102), cannot take off, please contact DJI support

These error messages are obtained by setting `DiagnosticsInformationCallback`.

[Image from DJI GO 4 app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdCpq.png):

Following error message is received

> "Cannot take off. Ensure the aircraft battery is properly connected."

I believe the error code 102 is equivalent to the error message `"Ensure the aircraft battery is properly connected."`. Our question is how to fetch this error message?

After some research with the DJI SDK we came across `DJIFlightError`.`FLAG_BATTERY_CONN_EXCEPTION`,
But there is no information available in SDK documentation on how to work with this.

Comment: did you check this https://forum.dji.com/thread-137621-1-1.html

Comment: Thank you Rahul! But the The issue I am facing is not about the battery error. Its about fetching those errors in the sample application that I am developing. I would like to see the exact error message instead of error codes.

Comment: Hi @abhishekmaharajpet the diagnosis module is being refactored, after the refactoring we will update this page for all the errors reported by diagnosis module: https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Diagnostics/DJIDiagnostics.html?search=camera_upgrade_error&i=0&#djidiagnostics_djidiagnosticserror_inline